# how to bind function on dynamically created node

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a placeholder enabling function

```
var t=document.createElement("input");
"placeholder" in t||$("input").each(function(){
   if("submit"!==$(this).attr("type")){
         var n=$(this),l=n.attr("placeholder");
         n.css("color","#ccc").val(l);
         n.focus(function(){("#ccc"==n.css("color")||"rgb(204, 204, 204)"==n.css("color"))&&n.val("").css("color","#000")});
         n.blur(function(){""==n.val()&&n.css("color","#ccc").val(l)})}
})
```

I can call this function on dom ready, but how to use this function on newly created `input`?

Comment: This is practically minified. Some occasional spaces would make my eyes hurt less.

Comment: Try checking out http://api.jquery.com/on/ which replaces .live(). It should bind events live

Comment: @Brentoe first param of .on and .live is an event name like focus or something, I don't know which to use, is there an event 'oncreate'?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to bind the `focus` and `blur` callbacks?

You might need `on()` which will bind event to elements that *may not* exists yet. It replaces the deprecates `live()` and `bind()` functions and is intended to bind handlers to *any event, now or in the future*.

```
$.on("focus", "input", function() {});
```

You need to supply the **event**, the **selector** and the **handler**.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Aesthete He means that he wants to add a placeholder attribute to the input. If you use focus, it will clear the placeholder text, meaning adding it is next to useless unless they blur the element. What he wants is to listen to DOMNodeInserted, test for an input, and apply the methods above to the input.

Comment: Then listen for the `DOMNodeInserted` event? `$.on("DOMNodeInserted"...`